# When calling ajax the result is not appearing on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am making a photo sharing website ( layout like pinterest ) , but when I am clicking a category in my menu the old content goes but the new content is not visible, however if i check inspect element in chrome browser the fetched contents are there.

I don't know how they are fetched and still not appearing in the required div.

below is the html code.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="main" id="main">
        <ul id="tiles">
            <li><img src="asd/12994.jpeg" /></li>
            <li><img src="asd/12995.jpeg" /></li>
            .
            .
            .
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am calling an ajax function to replace all contents in div with id main, below is the ajax code.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'strip_all.php',
    data: 'asa='+aq,
    cache:false,
    success:function(res) {
        $('#cat_on_oven_popping').css('display','none');
        $('#main').html(res);
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you not seeing any error in console for `data: 'asa='+aq`? I think it should be `data:{'asa='+aq}`

Comment: What's in res? Sounds like it messes up your HTML structure (ul, li, etc..)

Comment: res contains the category id

Comment: And don't you have to restructure it in `ul` and `li`s again?

Comment: i am getting following error( yellow precaution ) in the error consol  ------ event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: no Omri, its just to fetch the required data

Comment: Ok, what about `#cat_on_oven_popping` ? Is it a div that wraps your `main` div?

Comment: Have you tried putting `console.log(res);` in your success method? Does it get called? What is your `res`?

Comment: no Omri its just the category box whch pops out, i need to close this on click...

Comment: May be `#cat_on_oven_popping` might be a parent of `#main` and since you have set the display to none, it isn't showing up anything.

Comment: When you inspect the element in Chrome and see that data, does it have a `display: none;` attribute?

Comment: Mathias... i have tried console.log(res); , still there is no error...

Comment: okay omri....i will chk

Comment: yes omri...actually in the css it says li display none...but doesn't the javascript is suppose to make it block

Comment: Not sure, something in your javascript/code makes it display none. I'll phrase this in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, something makes your data have the `display: none;` attribute.

I can't tell you from the code you posted what it is since it's not there, and you said the `#cat_on_oven_popping` is not related.

Use the Dev Tools to see which property has that, and try to figure out what's adding that attribute.

(I would even remove the `$('#cat_on_oven_popping').css('display', 'none')` just to see what happens)

Comment: okay....how to put <li> display:block in jquery as i havn't assigned any class or id to this element

Comment: @user2365753 It shouldn't have `display: none;` by default. You can try adding: `$('#main').css('display', 'block');` on the ajax success to see what happens though.

Comment: #main is okay...but for the grid system the li are set as display none in css....so do i have to change this property in ajax success

Comment: @user2365753 If you still have the `ul` and `li` structure there even after you overridden it with your result, you can try `$('#main ul li').css('display', 'block');`

Comment: One thing i forgot to mention that if i increase the no of fetched images and scroll down the page the li containing images appears

Comment: @user2365753 That's weird :) Have you tried my suggestion in the last comment by the way?

Comment: @user2365753 Could be.. hard to tell from over here. Could you share the HTML structure in your `main` div after ajax ?

Comment: did u find any thing...this problem is drivin me crazy....i m stuck with this since last 4 hrs...

Comment: @user2365753 I see the HTML but can't really work with it. However, the line I suggested should be after the `$('#main').html(res);` line. Try switching

Comment: okay...ia hve tried....finally rcvg the result...thx a lot....but...now the grid is totally messed up...its all coming in a straight line( below each other) not filling the screen length....

Comment: @user2365753 Well at least now this problem is solved. Now it's just a UI problem (the best kind right??). Try to restructure it, create a new function that receives `res` and iterates over it to create a better HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch the error :

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'strip_all.php',
    data: 'asa='+aq,
    cache:false,
    success:function(res){
         $('#cat_on_oven_popping').css('display','none');
         $('#main').html(res);
    },
    error: function () {
            console.log(arguments);
    }
});
```

Do you get an error ?

PS: It's better to send a JSON to "data" like that :

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'strip_all.php',
    data: {
       'asa':aq
    },
    cache:false,
    success:function(res){
         $('#cat_on_oven_popping').css('display','none');
         $('#main').html(res);
    },
    error: function () {
            console.log(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: you should ask for the details in the comment.